# Choosing a random text value from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have an Excel spreadsheet like this:

| Checkbox | Value |
| --- | --- |
| FALSE | Value1 |
| TRUE | Value2 |
| TRUE | Value3 |
| FALSE | Value4 |

I want to create a list with FALSE values and choose a random text value from that list.
For choosing random text value I tried using CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN())
I tried to use IF(NOT(Checkbox), Value, "") but it gives empty cells, and I do not want that.

Answer (score 2):

With Microaoft-365, give a try to-

```
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(B2:B100,A2:A100=FALSE),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIFS(A2:A100,FALSE)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`=@SORTBY(B2:B5,A2:A5-RANDARRAY(ROWS(B2:B5)))`

If it's possible that `A2:A5` doesn't comprise a single `FALSE` entry, as per the comments from @Domenic:

`=IF(AND(A2:A5),"",@SORTBY(B2:B5,A2:A5-RANDARRAY(ROWS(B2:B5))))`

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I don't think the formula will return the desired result when all CheckBoxes are TRUE.

Comment: This is an elegant solution and very short, but I think for the sole purpose of selecting one random value, `SORTBY` is time consuming. I just compared this solution with Harun24hr for 1 million rows and it confirms my thought SORTBY sol: 1.38s, CHOOSEROWS sol: 0.15s. About 9 times faster, but at the end something we can wait.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that A2:B5 contains the data, try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,LARGE(IF(A2:A5=FALSE,ROW(B2:B5)-ROW(B2)+1),INT(RAND()*COUNTIF(A2:A5,FALSE)+1)))
```

For Dynamic Excel, though, there's no need to confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.